# connection between theory that is done in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and its application on discrete signal

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I have problems understanding connection between theory that is done in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and its application to discrete signals.

Look at this paper: http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~zhanghan/cs/Mallat_Zhang93.pdf

All theory is done for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$
and integrals, and that's all fine. On page 8(3404) functions $g$ 
are sampled with period $T$ so that we are able to perform calculations on a computer in order to get representation of some sampled function $f$. 
We use sum inner product and work with sequences instead of functions.

What allows us to use theory about square integrable functions on a sequence of numbers?

Comment: Eventhough your question seems to be quite general, one particular answer to it comes from Sampling Theorem which states that: properly taken samples of a continuous-time signal that belongs to a class of bandlimited signals, would represent the complete information contained within the analog signal itself. And therefore any processing done on the continuous time signal, as long as the intermediate results do not violate the bandlimitedness, can be achieved by manipulating those samples of it accordingly in the discrete time domain.

Comment: I know about it but I dont get how is it answer. So ok, I properly sample my bandlimited function so I can reconstruct it via sum with $sinc$ function. That is fine. but I wont work with that reconstruction (or should I ?) I work with my sampled function and sampled $g$ functions do inner product as a sum and justify all that with theory from $L^2$ ?

Comment: I have not checked the paper, but you have a separable Hilbert space, which means that there is a countable basis. This implies you can do everything with infinite coefficient sequences instead of continuously parameterised coefficients and integrals. Does that help?

Comment: Probably, could you give some link or book recomendation about that, I am not so sure I understood. what happens is I find overcomplete basis of translations , dilatations and modulations of $g$  , suppose signal is bandlimited.. so I have finite many functions in basis and do inner products with that functions to get info about signal. all that is done in $L^2$

Comment: @Jack if you are "sure" that your signals are not band limited then sampling theorem, of course, does not apply. And then I don't know if any other tool would help for "exact" discrete representations of infinite band continous signals...

Comment: oh no, ofcourse signal f is bandlimited, I tought of g then I said that they are not (they are some exponential functions), but however I cant see how nyquist sampling theorem is the answer

Comment: Maybe "A foundation on digital communication" by A. Lapidoth would help; it's not about DSP but explains very clearly how square-integrable signals can be represented as a sum of orthonormal basis functions: $\sum_k a_k \phi_k(t)$. Then, by operating on the sequence of numbers $a_k$, you get another function that can be represented in the same space, without the inconvenience of having to do operations with continuous signals.